# "NTFS Signature is missing"

Tags: linux, centos, mount, ntfs-3g

I am trying to mount two hard disks in a microserver running Centos 7.
Both disks contain large amounts of data and were previously used in a Windows machine so are NTFS format.

I have created two directories to use as mountpoints - `/media/drive1` and `/media/drive2`. I have the EPEL repo installed and have installed `ntfs-3g`.

When I try `mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/drive1` I get the following:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a partition 9e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I get the same error when trying to mount `/dev/sdb1` to `/media/drive2`.

I am fairly new to Linux and this is the first time I have tried mounting an NTFS drive. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use fdisk to analyse the format of the partitions "man fdisk" for further details

Comment: It could be that Windows enabled BitLocker without you knowing it, which is what happened on my system (Windows 10 Pro). Run `blkid` and look for `TYPE="BitLocker"`...